# How can I "label encode" this multi-label dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, label-encoding

Here is a small data frame that contains a very small slice of data that I need to encode. [DataFrame to Encode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxbGf.png)

My current effort in doing this is using SciKit-Learns LabelEncoder(),

```
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(["local", "animals", "local", "diet", "food", "health", "local", "police brutality", "police", "kids", "dogs"])
list(le.classes_)

(output) 
['animals',
 'diet',
 'dogs',
 'food',
 'health',
 'kids',
 'local',
 'police',
 'police brutality']
```

I have now added all my desired targets to the encoder, so now I need to start encoding. The problem is the LabelEncoder takes arguments like this.

```
le.transform(["local"]) #For the first row in the data frame
(output) array([6])
```

Now thats the correct encoding for the first row, but how would I do this for every other row? I don't think writing it by hand is very doable as my actual data set is about 6000 samples.

I'm also not sure if the targets should be comma separated or not, I can always change that, but my end goal is to get a new data frame with encoded labels instead of the categorial labels.

Also, since the encoder returns a single array, if I were to do the same things for every row, each with a different amount of labels (i.e (dogs, animals) instead of (local)), I would need to append every array to make a matrix, but that is also something I have no clue how I should do. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).  For sklearn multilabel models anyway, the expected format is the boolean array rather than an array of lists of integers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently too, here's a function that does the job:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

class MultiColumnLabelEncoder:
    def __init__(self,columns = None):
        self.columns = columns # array of column names to encode

    def fit(self,X,y=None):
        return self # not relevant here

    def transform(self,X):
        '''
        Transforms columns of X specified in self.columns using
        LabelEncoder(). If no columns specified, transforms all
        columns in X.
        '''
        output = X.copy()
        if self.columns is not None:
            for col in self.columns:
                output[col] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(output[col])
        else:
            for colname,col in output.iteritems():
                output[colname] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col)
        return output

    def fit_transform(self,X,y=None):
        return self.fit(X,y).transform(X)
```

And here's how you'd use it on your example

```
    dataset = MultiColumnLabelEncoder(columns = ["local", "animals", "local", "diet", "food", "health", "local", "police brutality", "police", "kids", "dogs"]).fit_transform(dataset)
```

Comment: Is this significantly different from using `OrdinalEncoder`?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I tried it and it gave me a KeyError: 'local'. My data frame has only one column called 'tags', with local being one of those tags. Could that be the problem? Even if I define the columns = ['tags'], it returns a new data frame with one number per row, not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer


mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

mlb.fit([["local", "animals", "local", "diet", "food", "health", "local", "police brutality", "police", "kids", "dogs"]])
```